# How to add a number to an index range of a pandas array

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, how can I operate on a subset of rows in a column, selected by index?

In particular, how can I add 1.0 to column y here, only where the date is greater than 2016-08-04?

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(
... index=[datetime.date.today(), datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(1)],
... data=[[1.2, 234], [3.3, 432]],
... columns=['x', 'y'])
              x    y
2016-08-04  1.2  234
2016-08-05  3.3  432

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't mind whether this is in-place or returns a new dataframe.

The answer in this case should be:

```
              x    y
2016-08-04  1.2  234
2016-08-05  3.3  433
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert the index to a DateTimeIndex it becomes easier:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.loc[df.index > '2016-08-04', 'y'] += 1
df
Out: 
              x    y
2016-08-04  1.2  234
2016-08-05  3.3  433
```

Comment: Pandas allows date comparisons with strings, so you could even just do `df.index > '2016-08-04'`.

Comment: @root much better. Thanks.

Comment: In my full code I already have a DateTimeIndex (I forgot this writing the question), using pandas.read_table with the `date_parser` argument.  It was just the `.loc` usage I hadn't got right somehow.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-inplace alternative, you can use `df.add`:

```
df.add(df.index > pd.to_datetime('2016-08-04'), axis=0, level="y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) for `DatetimeIndex` or [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) for the convenience function `date_range`. Either will allow you to set a `DatetimeIndex` that is natural to work with.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [[1.2, 234], [3.3, 432]],
    index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='today', periods=2, freq='D', normalize=True),
    columns=['x', 'y'])

df.loc[df.index > '2016-08-04', 'y'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.where` method on the `y` column.

```
df.y = df.y.where(df.index < datetime.date(2016, 8, 4), lambda k: k + 1)
```